# Как управлять поведением Session.create(Entity) через hbm.xml?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

Есть 2 связанные таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS engines (
  id    SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  model VARCHAR(25) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  power INTEGER            NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cars (
  id        SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  mark      VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  model     VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  engine_id INTEGER     NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (engine_id) REFERENCES engines (id)
);
```

Они связанны `many-to-one`. Один тип двигателя может быть использован в разных автомобилях. Моя задача сделать так, что-бы когда я добавляю `Car` c двигателем который уже есть в таблице `engines`, то добавлялся новый автомобиль с соответствующим `engine_id`. И только если такого двигателя пока нет, добавлялся и двигатель. Но пока получается что Hibernate пытается добавлять двигатель не проверяя есть ли он в `engines` и я получаю:

> ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "engines_model_key"
>         Detail: Key (model)=(test) already exists.

Что понятно, так как я сам поставил `model VARCHAR(25) UNIQUE` в `engines`.

Вот мои `hbm.xml`:

Автомобиль:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-mapping">

    <class name="ru.javavision.model.Car" table="cars">
        <id name="id" column="id">
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>
        <property name="mark" column="mark"/>
        <property name="model" column="model"/>

        <!--Прикрепляем сущьность двигателя-->
        <many-to-one name="engine" column="engine_id"
                     class="ru.javavision.model.Engine"
                     cascade="save-update" not-null="true"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Двигатель:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-mapping">

    <class name="ru.javavision.model.Engine" table="engines">
        <id name = "id" type = "int" column = "id">
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>
        <property name="model" column="model"/>
        <property name="power" column="power"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Запросы к базе я делаю через `SessionFactory`:

```
private final SessionFactory factory = ...;

public void create(@NotNull final Car car) {

    try (final Session session = factory.openSession()) {

        session.beginTransaction();

        session.save(car);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

Вопрос в следующем: могу ли я не меняя `session.save(car)` только за счет конфигурации в `<many-to-one name="engine" column="engine_id" class="ru.javavision.model.Engine" cascade="save-update" not-null="true"/>` или изменив только `hbm.xml` конфигурации настроить нужное мне поведение. Если да то как. Вероятно мне нужно поменять `cascade="save-update"` но метод тыка пока ничего не дал.

Буду признателен за любую помощь. Спасибо.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, вы пытаетесь создать экземпляр Car, который содержит Engine ? А когда делаете сейв, то выдает ошибку, т.к при сохранении база ругается, что Engine уже существует ? Чтобы этого избежать сначала сделайте фетч Engine (select engine e from engine  where model ... ) Потом подставьте данный Engine в Car и сохраняйте .

Comment: @aleshka-batman да если сначала сделать выборку по engine это понятно. А если сразу сохранять а поведение задать через конфигурации.